# WebMethod not working in ASP.Net Web Role (Web Forms)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, azure, webmethod

Repro:

- Open VS2013, File > New "Azure Cloud Service" Project > Add an "ASP.NET Web Role" (named as WebRole1)
- Select "Web Forms" template for the web role.
- Add [jquery-1.11.1.min.js](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js) and a new WebForm1.aspx to the WebRole1 Project.
- Add the following code to the  of WebForm1.aspx

  ```
  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "WebForm1.aspx/Foo",
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
                                   "application/json; charset=utf-8");
          },
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          data: "{a: 'webmethod!'}",
          success: function(data) {
              alert(data.d);
          },
          error: function() {
              alert("error");
          }
      });
  });
  ```
- Add the following function to the WebForm1 class in WebForm1.aspx.cs

  ```
  [WebMethod()]
  public static string Foo(string a)
  {
      return a;
  }
  ```
- Set WebRole1 project as Startup Project and run. The browser alerts "undefined".

But you can get "webmethod!" using plain ASP.NET WebForm project. What is wrong?

---

I noticed that in `url: "WebForm1.aspx/Foo"`: if you change the aspx part, the ajax fails; if you change the Foo part to whatever value, the ajax always succeed. This is unusual! In plain ASP.NET Web Form application, changing either part will result in "error"!

---

If you create an **Empty** ASP.NET Web Role, the ajax will succeed!!! What is going on?

Comment: Did you enabled page methods at page level via making it true?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScriptSerializer is pretty flexible, but it might be worth trying valid JSON in the data parameter, like:

```
data: '{"a": "webmethod!"}'
```

I believe JSS will handle keys/values in single quotes, even though that's not technically valid JSON, but the unquoted `a` might be a bit much.